# Identifying convex and concave portions of polygon using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon, geometry

I have a polygon shapefile depicting an island. For my study, I'm interested in two coastal features of the island: convex sections (portions of the coastline that extend into the ocean) and concave sections (portions of the coastline that recede into the island, like an embayment or lagoon).

To accomplish this, I have completed the following steps:

1. Convert the polygon into a polyline
2. Generate points along the island polyline boundary at 5km intervals
3. Split the polylines at the points, to create 5km polyline segments along the island
4. Used the Calculate Sinuosity tool in ArcMap, which measures deviation of a line from the shortest path, on all 5km polyline segments

However, the [Calculate Sinuosity tool](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=00e708a448b74810a0e805c4a97f9d46) doesn't distinguish *how* the line deviates from the shortest path. The direction of the line deviation (convex: toward the ocean; concave: receding inland) is relevant.

Is there a tool to calculate whether the line deviation falls under a more concave or convex shape for the entire island ?